# Why does it seem that the order of execution is not top->down in this function?

Tags: common-lisp, user-input, stdout

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script

(defvar a)
(defun main ()
  ;(write-line "Yes or no?"); This works in the correct order
  (print "Yes or no?")
  (setq a (read))
  (print a))
(main)
```

When executed it prompts for input and only after giving the input it prints `"Yes or no?"` (where my intention is for it to first print `"Yes or no?"` then take input). When I swap `print` for `write-line`
the order is as expected, though.
Why does `write-line` behave so differently from `print` in this case? Why does it seem that the order of execution is not top->down in this function? I want the function main execute `print` and `read` in the order that they appear
in the source file. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: @MartinPůda Thanks, it mostly does. I added a note about different behaviour of `write-line` to my question. It may not merit the answer but a comment would be appreciated.

Comment: This behavior isn't exclusive to Common Lisp; the underlying operating system buffers i/o, and that buffer must be flushed to send output to the desired device. "_Why does `write-line` behave so differently from `print` in this case?_" Typically a newline will flush the output buffer, and `write-line` adds a newline to the characters it sends to output, but `print` does not add that newline. Note that it is often best to explicitly flush the buffer, e.g., using `finish-output` or `force-output` instead of relying on newline behavior.

Comment: typically newlines flush in terminals, but not in file streams